# Python convert part of a tuple to string

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have this tuple:
**(1, 0, 0, 2)**

and i want a string like: **0 0 2**
(without the first number)

how can I do this?

Comment: `print(' '.join([str(num) for num in t[1:]]))`

Answer (score -1):

```
your_tuple = (1, 0, 0, 2)
result = ' '.join([str(v) for v in your_tuple[1:]])
```

An array of elements in the tuple excluding the first element is created and then joined by a space. The array should have string elements. Hence `str(v)` is to be applied.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
your_tuple = (1, 0, 0, 2)
your_string = ' '.join(map(str, your_tuple[1:]))
```